# ActiveX cannot create object vb6 application with crystal report8.5

Tags: sql-server, com, vb6, crystal-reports, activex

I inherited a program from my late dad its developed with vb6 and has sql server 2000 as the back end. when i try to print a report from the application it gives the error message "ActiveX cannot create object" but when i view the report from crytal report it displays everything. Please i need help

Comment: It might be beneficial if you could post the procedure the error occurs in, as well as the line that triggers the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really much to go on, but it looks like your program is missing some unspecified dependancy. Maybe you should check the installation was correct? It might be an idea to reinstall the program.

Comment: just re-installed the program and instead of the "ActiveX cannot cerate object error" it just displays the "OK" msgbox as if it has vprinted the report

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a Crystal reports activex control/dll that hasn't been registered, which means your app can't find it in the registry.

If you can work out which one it is, use regsrv32 to register it, otherwise try re-installing Crystal reports.

Comment: registered all of the services but the report is still not displaying

Answer (score 0):

The runtime version of the crystal report control is not correctly registered. Find & register 'crystl32.ocx', using regsvr. Ensure that it is in the WinSys path(i.e c:/Windows/System32). The dependacy files 'crystl32.dep' should also be on the path. This should sort you out.